# Why am I getting subprocess error wen I try to install certain django packages in cpanel?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to host my django application on cpanel. I have moved the project into the file manager and done all configurations. Now, I need to run some pip installs in the cpanel terminal and thats where the problem is. Whenever I try to do pip install django-allauth, I get a subprocess error and I dont know why. Django-allauth is not the only package that gives me this kind of error. psycopg2-binary does as well.

Solutions that I have already tried:

1. i have upgraded pip, wheel and setup tools.
2. I have changed the python versions being used for my project.
3. I have changed the django versions as wel.

yet, the problem persists. Please I really need help.

[image: image of the error from cpanel terminal]

Comment: I have changed the case of the caption.Can you please help me?

Comment: You are still using all caps in the body of your question. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Cpanel does not allow me to copy text from the terminal. That's why I had to post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use older releases from same library:

`pip install ...==1.0.1`